# How to find the set difference of two sorted arrays in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I would like to use an array `rows` for indexing rows of another array `x`. Initially, `rows` contains indices of all rows of `x` (and is therefor sorted). Throughout the program, some indices `exclude` are chosen to be removed from `rows`. Similar to `rows` itself, `exclude` is a sorted array.

What is the best way of finding the set difference of `rows` and `exclude`?

I have thought of a few different options, but I think their complexities are more than `O(n + m)`, where `n` is the length of `rows` and `m` is the length of `exclude`.

1. `new_rows = [r for r in rows if r not in exclude]`

This solutions requires looking up `exclude` every time and therefore, `O(mn)` complexity.

2. `new_rows = setdiff1d(rows, exclude, assume_unique=True)`

This will probably take `O(nlogm)`, but I'm not sure.

3. Convert `exclude` to a `dict` and run 1. The problem with this approach is that it requires extra memory, but it meets the complexity requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here are outlines of two O(n+m) options:

1) `heapq.merge` will combine two sorted sequences in linear time. As the combined sequence is sorted, shared indices will sit next to each other.

2) as `rows` as you describe it is a "thinned out range" I assume that the the max value of `rows` is not excessively large. You can therfore allocate an array `E` of that size (O(1) if we don't initialize it, i.e. use `np.empty`). Then you use `rows` and `exclude` to index into the empty array. For example, you write `E[rows] = 1` `E[exclude] = 0` and then check back `E[rows]` and remove all elements of `rows` at which E has changed from `1` to `0`.

Option 2 also works if the two sets are not sorted.